# how to pass id to a span element in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to pass Ids to a `span` tag which exist without the `id` attribute. These Ids which I pass should be done through `for` loop incrementing each loop and passing my `geneologicalSequenceNumber` into each `span` tag.

How do I select the element and pass my `id`

````
<div class="selecter-options">
<span value ="A">A<span>
<span value ="B">B<span>
<span value ="C">C<span>
<span value ="D">D<span>
</div>
```
Desired Output
```
<span id ="1" value ="A">A<span>
<span id ="2" value ="B">B<span>
<span id ="3" value ="C">C<span>
<span id ="4" value ="D">D<span>
````

For loop I used for selecting the element in my document using jquery:

```
for(var k = 0 ; k < productVersionIDs.length ; k++){
        var myid =productVersionIDs[k].genealogySequenceNumber;
        $('#productListPanel_add .versionIdSelectClass  +div .selecter-options span').attr('id', myid);
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your selector is correct use .eq(): eq(i) gives the access to ith item of jquery selector array

```
for(var k = 0 ; k < productVersionIDs.length ; k++){
        var myid =productVersionIDs[k].genealogySequenceNumber;
        $('.selecter-options span').eq(k).attr('id', myid);
                            }
```

i think `$('.selecter-options span').eq(k).attr('id', myid)` is ok if you havent other span with same class